# Polymer: prevent submitting form when input invalid

Tags: forms, validation, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a component that encapsulate an `paper-input` as you can see in the following code:

```
<dom-module id="my-p">
  <template>
    <div class="my-class>
        <paper-input
            type="number"
            value="{{value}}"
            name="{{name}}"
            error-message="Error"
            invalid="{{invalid}}"
            label="{{name}}"
            allowed-pattern="[0-9,]"
            required="{{required}}"></paper-input>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-p',
        properties: {
            name: String,
            value : {
                type: Number,
                notify : true
            },
            required : Boolean,
            invalid: {
              type: Boolean,
              value: false,
              notify: true
            },
        }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Besides, I have another component to add some previous component into a form:

```
<dom-module id="my-form">
  <template>
    <h2>My test</h2>
    <form is="iron-form" id="form" method="get">
        <my-p name="my input 1" value="{{value1}}" invalid="{{!_m(value1, value2)}}" required="true"></my-p>
        <my-p name="my input 2" value="{{value2}}" invalid="{{!_m(value1, value2)}}"></my-p>

        <paper-input name="paper" type="number" label="paper" required="true"></paper-input>

        <button type="submit">Send</button>
        <paper-button raised id="btn" on-click="_send">Send</paper-button>
    </form>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-form',
        _m(v1, v2) {
            var n1 = parseInt(v1);
            var n2 = parseInt(v2);
            var valid = n1 >= (n2 + 2);
            return valid;
        },_send() {
            console.log("ok2");
        }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

`required` attribute works when I click on first submit button: form is not submitted if required inputs are empty.

The problem is when any input is `invalid`: form is submitted.

Can I prevent submitting form if there is any `invalid` input?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it with `button`, instead call your own function where you manually check if is form valid and then manually submit form.

`iron-form` has `validate` function but i don't think ti will work here since you are using encapsulated paper-input. Fortunately, `paper-input` has `submit` function too, so you call this function on every single `my-p` element.

example:

```
   <form is="iron-form" id="form" method="get">
        <my-p name="my input 1" value="{{value1}}" required></my-p>

        <paper-input name="paper" type="number" label="paper" required="true"></paper-input>

        <paper-button raised on-tap="checkAndSendForm">Send</paper-button>
    </form>
```

Then, inside JS, define function `checkAndSendForm`:

```
checkAndSendForm() {
  var validated = true;
  var inputs = this.querySelectorAll("my-p[required]"); // select all required inputs
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){ // iterate through all required inputs
    if(!inputs[i].validate()) {
      validated = false; // input validation failed and will stop submit
    }
  }

  if(validated) {
    this.$.form.submit(); // manually submit the form
  }
}
```

Inside `my-p` element you have to define function `validate` which will just call another `validate` function on `paper-input`.

```
validate() {
  this.querySelector("paper-input").validate(); // validate paper-input
}
```

And i would also suggest you to set `reflectToAttribute` on `required` property inside `my-p` element. But this is only because I used selector  `querySelectorAll("my-p[required]");`

```
required: {
  type: Boolean,
  reflectToAttribute: true
}
```

Comment: Kuba, `querySelectorAll` function does not returns anything.

Comment: ok, then you can use `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll` if this doesn't return anything, then mistake is in selector. So just try to set only `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll("my-app")` and tell if this works. Man you have to try on your own. I will not guide you through everything :)